# instert div before a element tag of an image

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that will look in a div and find all images.  it then wraps the image in a new div, creates a second div that houses a button, and this is used to do an image hover effect with another script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get the images from whatever element contains them.    
    var postImgs = $('#primary img');

    postImgs.each(function applyPinterestButton(){

    // This allows the post-writer to add a class of "nopin" to
    // whatever images they don't want to have pinned.
    if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('nopin') == -1){       
        // Wrap the image in a container.
        $(this).wrap('<div class="showPin"/>');         

        // Add the pinterest button and link into the container.
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class ="pinIt"><a href="buttonlink.html" target="_blank"><img src="button.jpg" /></a></div>');           
    }
});
```

the before jQuery html looks like this:

```
<a href="http://originalimagelink.html"><img src="originalimage.jpg"></a>
```

but after the script, the jquery is wrapping only the img, like this:

```
<a href="originalimagelink.html">
<div class="showPin">
    <div class="pinIt">
        <a href="buttonlink.html">
            <img src="button.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <img src="originalimage.jpg">
</div>
</a>
```

I need it to wrap the `img` and `a` elements.  so the end result is something like this:

```
<div class="showPin">
    <div class="pinIt">
        <a href="buttonlink.html">
            <img src="button.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="originalimagelink.html"><img src="originalimage.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).attr('class')`? Put an alert and check before calling `if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('nopin') == -1){ }`. I guess its `undefined`!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Get the images from whatever element contains them.    
  var postImgs = $('#primary img');
  postImgs.each(function() {

  // This allows the post-writer to add a class of "nopin" to
  // whatever images they don't want to have pinned.
  if(!$(this).hasClass('nopin')) {      

    // Wrap the image in a container.
    $(this).parent().wrap('<div class="showPin"/>');         

    // Add the pinterest button and link into the container.
    $(this).parent().parent().prepend('<div class ="pinIt"><a href="buttonlink.html" target="_blank"><img src="button.jpg" /></a></div>');           

  }
  });
});
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gfE7m/2/

Comment: didn't know you could do `.parent().parent()` thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Well... that is not the best approach, frankly speaking. I just found no better solution quickly.

Answer (score 4):

1. You may want to start in the image's parent element.

   ```
   // Get the images from whatever element contains them.    
   var postImgs = $('#primary img').parent();
                                 --^^^^^^^^^--
   ```
2. You can make use of the [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function.

   ```
   // This allows the post-writer to add a class of "nopin" to
   // whatever images they don't want to have pinned.
   if(!$(this).hasClass('nopin')){
            --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/39/) code:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').not('.nopin').each(function(){
        $(this).closest('a').wrap('<div class="showPin"/>').before('<div class="pinIt"><a href="buttonlink.html"><img src="button.jpg"></a></div>');
  })
});​
```